# A command-line tool to convert SWF to SVG?

Tags: conversion, swf, svg

I need to convert a whole bunch of static SWFs to SVGs and I was hoping that there was some sort of command line tool I could use so I could script it with PowerShell. Does anyone know of such an application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sourceforge seems to have an SWF to SVG converter.

http://swf2svg.sourceforge.net/

Or, the other way around

http://svg2swf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This, unfortunately is a web-based application. As the title of the question states, I need to automate this from a command-line, with no dependencies on an internet connection.

Comment: Sorry, I followed the link to the source code and missed the "Web converter tool" midway down the page.  The svg2swf tool is command line so I stupidly assumed the swf2svg was too.

Answer (score 1):

Research In Motion's development kit has a command line utility for this. You can get it in the dev kit [here](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/themes/devtools.jsp). The file is in the bin directory and is called swftosvg.exe.

> Usage:
>     swftosvg [-help] [-version] [-o 'outputfile'] [-d 'imagedir'] 'inputfile'.swf
>   Options:
>     -help
>       display this help message
>     -version
>       display product version
>     -o
>       write the result of the conversion to 'outputfile' [default: 'inputfile'.svg]
>     -d
>       write converted images to directory 'imagedir' [default: same directory as 'outputfile']

Answer (score 0):

SWF is not necessarily static, where SVG usually is, there's no real way of converting SWF to SVG.

Comment: Actually, all of the SWFs I have are static.

Comment: Also, I know it can be done, as I've done it in the past, but I can't remember the app I used because it was two years ago.

Comment: @blesh doesn't matter, they generally aren't... SWF and SVG are two very different kind of files...

Comment: I've done it in the past. So yes, it can be done. In fact, there's a [web tool to do it][1], but what I'm looking for is a command line tool to do it. [1]: http://www.eprg.org/~sgp/swf2svg.html

Comment: @blesh I see... Another thing learned today :)

Comment: I also found SWFRIP on sourceforge, but it doesn't do anything from the command line.

Comment: @blesh: I think the web tool you referenced is a bit outdated. "only been tested with Flash 3 files".

Answer (score 0):

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999406/how-do-i-convert-a-swf-vector-animation-to-an-animated-svg-or-sequence-of-still-s) it myself.

The tool URL is [here](http://www.mgatelabs.com/cms/flashexploit/POST/2/), it requires Java, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked a few links and they all return 404 or are redirects. Since this is a very old question.

I've found a way to do this using Python library [pyswf](https://github.com/timknip/pyswf) on GitHub. The readme shows how to write a simple CLI that will convert SWF to SVG.

Copy-pasting it  for reference:

```python
from swf.movie import SWF
from swf.export import SVGExporter

# create a file object
file = open('path/to/swf', 'rb')

# load and parse the SWF
swf = SWF(file)

# create the SVG exporter
svg_exporter = SVGExporter()

# export!
svg = swf.export(svg_exporter)

# save the SVG
open('path/to/svg', 'wb').write(svg.read())
```

Note that PIP version was not working, as I'm writing this, with Python 3, I was needed to install pip2.7 to use the library.

If you have a problem installing pip2.7 here is a question on StackOverflow: [how to use python2.7 pip instead of default pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26267333/387194)